# Replication between SQL Servers resides in Windows Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, azure-virtual-machine

Hello I am facing one issue during snapshot replication between SQl servers reside in Windows Azure Virtual Machine.

I had 2 VM with below configuration
1) Windows server 2012 (Installed sql server 2012 with msdn licence)
2) SQL server 2008 R2 (Databases reside on this server, on this i had created publisher for replication)

Now when i creating subscriber over target sql server (1st server) then while selecting publisher connection it shows me error in connecting as shown below image.

Is there any need to create virtual network? in future target server would be on premises server instead of Azure VM.

**Note : For both VM i had opened 1433 port and enabled Mixed Mode Authentication.**

[image]

Comment: Faced this problem once in a non Azure environment and got it solved with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212032/sql-server-replication-requires-the-actual-server-name-to-make-a-connection-to-t maybe it helps

Comment: @larrydahooster I had already looked with that before but that was not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution by adding alias entry in host file on VM (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc)

**[IP Here instead of cloudapp.net URL]           [SQL server instance name]**

Answer (score 3):

Create an alias in SQL Server Configuration Manager and give it the name the replication component expects. The alias contains the cloupapp url and port.
Now reconnect using the simple alias. Just did this for my cloudapp.net VM.

Answer (score 0):

So for clarification, using the example above, the solution as I've experienced it, is to create a SQL Server alias for the server name shown in the error message. In this case, the alias name should be `SQL-AZURE` and the server should be the server name as shown at the top of the error message dialog:

```
catalysttg.cloudapp.net, port no 1433, protocol tcp/ip
```