# SQL Replication (subscriber) can't connect to publication

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I have 2 virtual machines, one with SQL Server 2008 R2 and another with SQL Server 2012 Express.

On 1 I have configuration for replication (publication), and I would like to setup Express version as a subscriber.

But I can't to connect to publisher

> SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a
>   connection to the server. Specify the actual server name, 'XXXX'.
>   (Replication.Utilities)

I have tried to cheat and added XXXX server name to hosts file, but it doesn't help.

Additionally I used to run http://www.hagrin.com/332/fixing-sql-server-replication-requires-actual-server-name-make-connection-server-error action for setup publication in correct way

What I need to do for successful connection ?

Comment: This error typically occurs when the Publisher or Subscriber hostname has been renamed at some point.  Ted Krueger discusses this in detail here and provides a possible solution:  http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/replication-requires-the-actual-server

Comment: I chganged it. And see the correct names but any way I can't connect from sql express 2012 to replication on SQL server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replication is very picky about the actual server name. At both the publisher and subscriber, run `select @@servername` to see what you should be using. My guess is that you've got a DNS alias for at least one of them.

Comment: names are the same on both servers. What do you mean with DNS alias ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212032/sql-server-replication-requires-the-actual-server-name-to-make-a-connection-to-t this is the answer (from user eLVik)