# MS SQL Server replication subscriber connection error: Specify the actual server name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

I have 2 virtual PC. I would like to use Replication between them.

[image: Shema]

**B** - is SQL Server 2008 R2, 
**A** - is SQL Express 2012

Screenshot from Management Studio on server A, as you can see I can connect to B server by IP (or by name but only in case If I change HOST file).

If I try to start new subscription wizard on server **A**, I am getting an error:

*SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Specify the actual server name, '**B**_StagingDB'. (Replication.Utilities)*

I am getting the same error then try to create new replication from server **A** on server **B**.
(Additionally I can create new replication on server **B** directly.)

What I need to do to make it work ? 
Thanks.
P.S
[As you can see I have change server name on B](http://mssqlnuggets.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/error-sql-server-replication-requires-the-actual-server-name-to-make-a-connection-to-the-server-connections-through-a-server-alias-ip-address-or-any-other-alternate-name-are-not-supported-specify/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sp_dropserver, sp_addserver : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx

Comment: ok, sorry, I haven't seen it. I don't see a lot of things by the way. Why do you say "as you can see I can connect to B server by IP (or by name but only in case If I change HOST file)", the machines cannot resolve the other machine name ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212032/sql-server-replication-requires-the-actual-server-name-to-make-a-connection-to-t this is the answer (from user eLVik)