# Replicate SQL Server over IP

Tags: sql-server, replication

I'm trying to replicate from SQL Server 2008 to a remote SQL Server 2005. I can't add subscribers with SQL Login, and I'm getting this error.

[image]

I tried adding aliases, editing `hosts` file, adding the subscriber directly form T-SQL with no success.

Comment: The error message is extremely clear. You cannot do it like this. It clearly states in the error message that what you are trying to do is not possible. What part of it are you not understanding?

Comment: What the error message implies is that remote replication is not supported altogether in sql server. If it's true, it's really surprising. So, I'm looking for workarounds or alternate solutions.

Comment: Try this article as a great starting place. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151319.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212032/sql-server-replication-requires-the-actual-server-name-to-make-a-connection-to-t)