# SQL Server subscription requires actual server name using azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

I have created an Azure VM, along with sql server.   I can connect to it just fine.  I'm able to create databases.  What my goal is to move entirely to the azure cloud.

Locally on-premise I created a publication.

Now I'm trying to set the Azure db as a subscriber

**Error**

```
Cannot connect to myazuredatabase.westus.cloudapp.azure.com,1433.

===================================

SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Specify the actual server name, 'myazuredatabase'. (Replication.Utilities)
```

I followed a pluralsight guide, it is a bit outdated.   I do have DNS name etc..    what is wrong?

Comment: Are you using SQL in a VM (IaaS) or SQL DB (PaaS) for your SQL Server?

Comment: IaaS in VM  - I did that mostly because many years ago PaaS SQL was not the same and limited ...

Comment: what does `@@servername` returns

Comment: check this out:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212032/sql-server-replication-requires-the-actual-server-name-to-make-a-connection-to-t

Comment: `@@servername`  returns   `myazuredatabase`

Comment: Problem is that I do that it is looking locally

Comment: Looks like typical replication issue to me, have you tried setup an [alias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190445%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on local machine for myazuredatabase.westus.cloudapp.azure.com?

Comment: Also make sure you add alias under both SQL Native Client Configuration and SQL Native Client Configuration(32bit).

Comment: Should I do alias and such on my local desktop or azure vm  ?

Comment: @JeremyMiller Do that on the machine where your on-perm SQL Server resides.

Comment: on perm = ?     1. I have Local Desktop machine with SSMS  2. On premise Server   3.  Azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested it with snapshot replication after back to the office. In your scenario, **you would need to setup 2 aliases in your environment**:

1. **Alias on your local machine** for SSMS. This needs to be done under SSCM>>SQL Native Client Configuration(32bit).
2. **Alias on on-premise server**. This needs to be done under SSCM>>SQL Native Client Configuration if you have 64 bit SQL Server. Otherwise just setup it under SSCM>>SQL Native Client Configuration(32bit).

Here's what you alias should look like:
[image]

Comment: I added to the 32 bit.   For Now I am using my local machine which is running a restored copy of a database so i used SSCM and added in the alias ,   locally i'm using SQL server 2014,   the Azure VM is running sql server 2016   ,  the NEW error message that I am getting is  `The selected subscriber does not satify the minimum version compatibility level of the selected publication`

Comment: So one is 2014 and other is 2016 ,  only thing that i can think of is that i restored a database that was originally on sql server 2008 R2  ,   thoughts?