# SQL Server Replication with Publication and Subscriptions not working as it requires the actual server name to make a connection

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, database-mirroring

I have a Computer / SQL Server machine that ALL software ( 500 applications) know as  `TMPSQL2`

So on this `TMPSQL2` machine I have a Database that I want to setup replication with doing Publication.

Problem is that

### SQL Server is unable to connect to server 'tmpsql2'.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Connections through a server alias, IP address, or any other alternate name are not supported. Specify the actual server name, 'TMPSQL7'. (Replication.Utilities)

So that I run

```
select @@servername
```

Sure enough it is really `TMPSQL7` that i guess someone renamed ?  many years ago??

So how can I do a Publication with this issue.   Is is NOT an option to rename this machine,  many applications are "looking" for `TMPSQL2`

So the error states that alias is not allowed?   I was hoping to do a configuration  SSCM alias addition ( pending that is not harmful)

1. Can I still do a publication/subscription,  if so ,  how?
2. Anything else recommended that will replicate or mirror the database with a new backup i restored on a new machine?

Answer (score 0):

From your SSMS, can you connect to TMPSQL2 or TMPSQL7? Or please read this helpful link [Sql Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212032/sql-server-replication-requires-the-actual-server-name-to-make-a-connection-to-t?rq=1)

Comment: TMPSQL2 is how everybody connects ,  and that link i read earlier,  renaming is not an option.

Comment: It doesn't rename the machine. It updates SQL Server name.

Comment: How will 500 applications that are compiled on 20 servers know to connect when they are literally looking for TMPSQL2 ?

Comment: If replication can accept IP or alias, you don't have the problem.

Comment: But through the GUI I cannot do this.  So basically this would have to be done with T-SQL code ..   So basically you really don't have a true answer or solution.

Comment: The link I gave you is the solution and it is T-SQL. A possible scenario is,  a SQL Server was installed on a machine TMPSQL2, the SQL Server default to the same name as the machine name - TMPSQL2. If another SQL Server TMPSQL7 migrated to TMPSQL2, and restored/overwrote by old master database with the name TMPSQL7. So now 'select @@servername' become TMPSQL7. Execute the T-SQL in the link, it gives you back the SQL Server name to TMPSQL2.  It doesn't change the machine name. Thanks.

Comment: No,  I am trying to create a publication,  that T-sql  is not going to work