# Cannot add new subscription to remote SQL Server Publication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-replication, transactional-replication

I have this setup:

- A publisher SQL Server Standard 2014 instance named `GMSSERVER\SQLSTANDARD` on `Server A`
- A subscriber SQL Server 2014 Express instance named `CLAUDIOGMS\SQLEXPRESS2014` on `Server B`

When I try to add a new subscription from `CLAUDIOGMS\SQLEXPRESS2014` I have a problem. I try to connect to `server A` using Server name `GMSSERVER` but I got the following error:

> Cannot connect to GMSSERVER.
>
> SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Specify the actual server name, 'GMSSERVER\SQLSTANDARD'.
>   (Replication.Utilities)
>
> Program Location:
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ReplicationSqlConnection.CheckServerAlias(ServerConnection conn)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ReplicationSqlConnection.ValidateConnection (UIConnectionInfo connInfo, IServerType server)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

If I try to connect using server name `GMSSERVER\SQLSTANDARD` instead, then I got a network related error.

The strange thing for me is that I can connect to `GMSSERVER\SQLSTANDARD` from `server B` using Server name `GMSSERVER` with no problems in SQL Server Management Studio but not in the subscription wizard

Comment: Have you searched Google for "sql server named instance replication"? Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212032/sql-server-replication-requires-the-actual-server-name-to-make-a-connection-to-t  ?

Comment: Yes, many times. The actual server name is equal to the real name. I have corrected that, but still I'm having the error.

Comment: I solved it following these steps to create an allias.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14481413/3542984
thanks @Alex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212032/sql-server-replication-requires-the-actual-server-name-to-make-a-connection-to-t)